# Comparar un carácter con cadena String?

Tags: c#, string

¿Cómo comparo letras ingresadas con una cadena `string`? Sé que la posición de la letra en la cadena se obtiene con `palabra.Substring`.

Estoy intentando comparar letras ingresadas con una cadena, la cual ingreso por teclado, algo así como el muñeco ahorcado.

Hasta ahora este es mi código:

```
while (i <= palabra.Length)
{
    Console.WriteLine(" Digite la letra :");
    letra = Console.ReadLine();

    comparacion = palabra.Substring(i, 1);

    if (letra == comparacion)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(comparacion);
        palabra.Substring(i, 1);

    }

    if (letra != comparacion)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(50, 5);
        Console.Write("O");
    }
    i++;
```

Comment: No entiendo del todo la pregunta. ¿Podrás **[edit]** explicando qué comparación estás intentando hacer? Por favor agrega un ejemplo.

Comment: Hola deberías ser mas explicito para que podamos entenderte y así puedes recibir respuestas mas rápidas.

Comment: Gracias , estoy intentando comparar letras ingresadas con un cadena la cual ingreso por Teclado... Algo así como el muñeco aorcado

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero sería que de verdad trabajes con un carácter mas bien que con una cadena para la sentencia siguiente:

```
letra = Console.ReadLine(); // esto te devuelve una cadena que tal vez contenga mas de una letra.
```

Para cambiar el tipo de la variable `letra` a `char` en vez de `string`, pudieras hacer la conversión algo así como:

```
letra = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // esto te devuelve un char si de verdad la cadena contiene un solo carácter.
```

Puedes usar `char.TryParse()` también si deseas verificar la cadena antes de convertirla a un `char`, pero esa es la idea general.

Una vez que tienes a `letra` de tipo `char`, ahora puedes comparar con cualquier letra que forma parte de la cadena `palabra` usando un índice. Por ejemplo:

```
if (letra == palabra[0])
{
    Console.WriteLine("La primera letra de la palabra corresponde");
}

if (letra == palabra[1])
{
    Console.WriteLine("La segunda letra de la palabra corresponde");
}

// ...
```

Esta idea se puede usar en un bucle también si lo deseas. Por ejemplo:

```
for (int i = 0; i < palabra.Length; i++)
{
    if (letra == palabra[i])
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"La posición #{i+1} en la palabra corresponde a la letra");
    }
}
```

La ventaja de trabajar usando el índice de la cadena mas bien que usar un `Substring` es que te evitas de crear cadenas temporarias innecesarias, una operación relativamente costosa. No creo que en tu programa sea un problema que vayas a notar, pero en programas mas grandes, el crear cadenas temporarias innecesariamente puede afectar el rendimiento de forma notable.

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que lo que quieres saber es si la letra se encuentra en la palabra, si es así deberías recorrer la palabra y tener un contador que aumente cada vez que un carácter de la palabra se igual a la letra.

```
string cadena="Hola"; 
for (int i=0;i<cadena.Length;i++){ 
       if(cadena.substring(i,1) == 'a') //aquí comparas la letra que buscas
         Console.WriteLine("{0}",cadena.substring(i,1)); 
}
```

Comment: Exacto amigo como seria estoy iniciando esto de la programacion

Comment: quiza lo de esta página te ayude

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/7a97f901-12b7-4e89-aa29-c60240e9dde6/buenos-dias-como-puedo-saber-si-un-string-contiene-una-letra-o-caracter-determinado?forum=vcses

Comment: Ok Muchas gracias

Comment: string cadena="Hola";
for (int i=0;i<cadena.Length;i++){
Console.WriteLine("{0}",cadena.substring(i,1));

Comment: string cadena="Hola";
for (int i=0;i<cadena.Length;i++){ if(cadena.substring(i,1) == 'a')
Console.WriteLine("{0}",cadena.substring(i,1)); }

Comment: @JaphSxas edité tu respuesta para que muestre correctamente el código. Lee el [comentario en la edición](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/35134/revisions)

Comment: Listo ahora lo reviso. gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si te refieres a la comparación de cadenas, tienes una función en la librería  que es strcmp, su sintaxis es strcmp(cadena1, cadena2) y devuelve un valor de tipo int (0 si las cadenas son iguales).
No sé si esto responde a tu pregunta, espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Debes estar pensando en el lenguaje `c` o algo así. Pero la pregunta es para C#. De todas maneras, la pregunta no es clara.